# Child process exited with status 254 error when extracting a tar.xz file

Tags: command-line, tar

I'm trying to extract a tar.xz file with `tar` in Mac OS X Lion. I'm using `bsdtar 2.8.3 - libarchive 2.8.3`. I'm able to use tar to extract anything else I've tried (.zip, .tar, .tar.gz, etc.), but when I try to extract the file ([this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cclive/files/0.7/cclive-0.7.11.tar.xz/download) file to be precise) using `tar -Jxf cclive-0.7.11.tar.xz`, I get this error:

```
tar: Error opening archive: Child process exited with status 254Child process exited with status 254
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same error here (tried GNU tar and the one included in OS X).

You are missing the `xz` compression program which tar tries to use.

Either install a precompiled `xz` from [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/macpkg/files/XZ/5.0.4/) or, if you are like me, download the source from http://tukaani.org/xz/ and compile it yourself:

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

(Unless told otherwise, `./configure` installs `xz` in `/usr/local/bin`. You possibly want to add it to `$PATH`.)

Then:

```
$ xz --decompress cclive-0.7.11.tar.xz
$ l cclive-0.7.11.tar 
-rw-r--r-- 1 jaume 1832960 2012-12-12 15:18 cclive-0.7.11.tar
```

Now untar as usual:

```
$ tar xf cclive-0.7.11.tar
```

Comment: ```brew install xz``` also works if you are already using [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/)

Comment: `port install xz` also works if you are using [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/)

Answer (score 0):

```
brew install xz
```

.. then repeat the original command